# Email ID filter using freetext sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, freetext

I cannot able to filter email from table using 'freetext' in sql server.
For ex:

```
select *
from abc
where column = 'abc@gsd.com'
```

is getting all data having @ and .com think so.

Comment: Your query only returns *exact* matches.

Comment: Your query should return the desired result and exact match, It seems correct. Please share your table structure with sample data and the desired output.

Comment: sorry my query is - select * from abc where freetext(xyz,asb@email.com)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this Query Works fine for your Case:

SELECT *
FROM ABC
WHERE COLUMN LIKE '%@%.com'

Thanks